# [ROS groovy] cant open rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cant open rviz.
distribution groovy
PC enviroment vitualbox ubuntu12.04
USE PC MAC

I finished building rviz package.
When I open rviz package,rviz crash. Virtualbox crash,too.

error massage

ERROR: 0:10: 'lightness' : redefinition
ERROR: 0:23: 'expression' :  left of '[' is not of type array, matrix, or vector
ERROR: 0:29: 'expression' :  left of '[' is not of type array, matrix, or vector
ERROR: 0:35: 'expression' :  left of '[' is not of type array, matrix, or vector
ERROR: 0:41: 'expression' :  left of '[' is not of type array, matrix, or vector
ERROR: 0:47: 'expression' :  left of '[' is not of type array, matrix, or vector
ERROR: 0:53: 'expression' :  left of '[' is not of type array, matrix, or vector
oord[I in GLSLProgram::compile at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLSL/src/OgreGLSLExtSupport.cpp (line 65)
[ WARN] [1372654229.085136857]: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1425)
[ WARN] [1372654229.088285128]: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/src/OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1425)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66298/%5Bros-groovy%5D-cant-open-rviz/) by [Ichiro suzuki](https://answers.ros.org/users/5224/ichiro-suzuki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try disabling hardware acceleration? See http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0